# How to access a macro from a mod.rs within the same directory in Rust 2018?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to use a macro that lives in the `mod.rs` file in the same directory without the use directive?

My project structure is as follows:

```
src
 |-- ui
      |-- mod.rs
      |-- alarm.rs
```

Now in `mod.rs` I have

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! pack {
    ($container:expr, $widget:expr, $expand:expr) => {
        $container.pack_start($widget, $expand, true, crate::consts::DIALOG_BOX_SPACING_U32)
    };
}
```

But in `alarm.rs` I cannot access this macro using `super::pack!()`. How can I access a macro defined in `mod.rs`? For reference, I can access functions using `super::a_pub_fn(arg)` way with no issues.

Comment: In short, `crate::pack!();` works because macros always live at the top-level of a crate. But this is a duplicate nonetheless.

Comment: You need to add `#[macro_use]` in your mod declaration.